# Create docker-compose project in JetBrains Rider solution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rider

I'm not able to create a docker-compose project in my solution using Jetbrains Rider.
There are no docker projects available when I right-click Solution -> Add -> New Project.
I don't seem to find any related questions having the same problem.
Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have a similar problem

Comment: No I was not able to find it in Rider, so I switched to Visual Studio to create it. (right click project)  But keep in mind that only Docker in Linux containers is supported. I don't think the project-file is required to work with docker, you could just create the docker-compose files yourself in the solution. But in my case, I wanted the project structure. Other than that, I also use my Visual Studio for debugging since Rider does not attach to my debugger (which is a shame, cause I don't like switching to VS)

Comment: I'm on mac so I desided to create dcproj and link to this file docker-compose files, and add to sln file. So everything is working. Visual Studio For Mac didn't helped About debugging, it's strange, because I don't have such problems, .net debugger even works in VS Code